# The end listener isn't shown

Tags: node.js

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    read = fs.createReadStream();

read.on("data", chunk => {
console.log("Reading...");
});

read.on("end", () => {
console.log("Finished.");
});
```

this works as expected, showing:

```
Reading...
Finished.
```

But, when i use only the end event, nothing is shown

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    read = fs.createReadStream();

read.on("end", () => {
console.log("Finished.");
});
```

Why this happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the stream won't flow until there's a listener for the `data` event.

And, thinking about it, it's a good thing it doesn't flow until you attach a `data` event (or manually read from it) because this allows your code to have time to set up the `data` listener before you would miss any data flowing, particularly if there are async operations you're waiting on before you set everything up.

Comment: so, is necessary the `data` event in all `async methods like this`

Comment: @J.Uchu - Not all async methods.  Just streams.  If you never set it up to read any data from the stream, then it never gets to the end.